# Powering 3 identical laptops using a solar panel

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, solar-cell, laptop

I have 3 identical laptops rated at 45W and 20V. The combined wattage of all 3 is 135W. I want to charge these laptops via a solar cell. Do I go for a solar cell rated 135W 20V or one rated 45W 20V?

Comment: 45 W < 135 W, so that's not going to work. Moreover, your raw panel will most likley output an open circuit voltage too high for your laptops and destoy them. Look for a solar regulator with 20 V output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

The output of a solar panel is not voltage regulated.  20V will only be the "nominal" voltage.  You may get more or less than that.

The wattage of the panel is quoted under ideal conditions.  That is direct sunlight onto the face of the panel, and the panel is not too hot.  In the real world, you will only occasionally get 135W out of a 135W panel.

So you need an over-sized panel (or a group of panels), and you need a voltage regulator so you actually get 20V.

Answer (score 0):

You need a buck-boost converter with UVLO cut off, preferably with MPPT control.   Look for LT8490, not a cheap solution and not available to buy, except from some questionable manufacturers.

The other way is to put them in series, having 60V. Then you need a buck converter, only. Cheapest is to use two panels in series - 40V and buck converter with UVLO cut off. The one is based on TI's BQ24650. But if fails, you can get 40V on its output.

To charge at 135W you may need several cells, since the nominal power is declard for sollar irradiance at 1100 W/m^2. You could charge one laptop at time.